# How do we know what year in-universe events happen?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The [ASOIAF wiki](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Main_Page) gives the year of events whenever possible. But I can't tell how these are determined in the source material. I recently re-read *A Game of Thrones* and am starting in on a re-read of *A Clash of Kings*, and not once did I see any reference to how many years it has been since Aegon's Conquest (apparently how years are measured in Westeros), nor any references to when the new year starts. Particularly surprising to me is that the wiki confidently places almost all the events in *A Game of Thrones*, from Jon Arryn's death to the Battle of the Green Fork and the Battle of the Camps, in 298 AC. How did the fandom determine that? The wiki has calculation pages but they seem to start from the assumption that almost everything in *A Game of Thrones* happens in 298 AC but no source is given for that claim as far as I can tell.

Edit: I want to emphasize I'm interested in the basis for the claimed precision. How do we know Jon Arryn didn't die in 297, or that The Battle of the Camps didn't happen in 299?

Answer (score 1):

The Sack of King's Landing takes place in 283 AC, taken from the Appendix in *A Dance with Dragons*:

> In the 283rd year after Aegon's Conquest, Robert of House Baratheon, Lord of Storm's End, overthrew the Mad King, Aerys II Targaryen, to win the Iron Throne. His claim to the crown derived from his grandmother, a daughter of King Aegon V Targaryen, though Robert preferred to say his warhammer was his claim.
>
> <sub>[*A Dance with Dragons*, Appendix, "House Baratheon"](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons-Appendix)</sub>

The pregnant Queen Rhaella and Prince Viserys are sent to Dragonstone not long before the Sack of King's Landing when Aerys II heard of Rhaegar's death at the Battle of the Trident.

> "Rhaegar met Robert on the Trident, and you know what happened there. When the word reached court, Aerys packed the queen off to Dragonstone with Prince Viserys. Princess Elia would have gone as well, but he forbade it. Somehow he had gotten it in his head that Prince Lewyn must have betrayed Rhaegar on the Trident, but he thought he could keep Dorne loyal so long as he kept Elia and Aegon by his side.
>
> <sub>*A Storm of Swords*, "Jaime V"</sub>

Daenerys is born nine moons into the flight to Dragonstone, most likely in 284 AC now, I expand on that a bit more [in this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/174687/58193).

> She had been born on Dragonstone nine moons after their flight, while a raging summer storm threatened to rip the island fastness apart. They said that storm was terrible. The Targaryen fleet was smashed while it lay at anchor, and huge stone blocks were ripped from the parapets and sent hurtling into the wild waters of the narrow sea. Her mother had died birthing her, and for that her brother Viserys had never forgiven her.
>
> <sub>*A Game of Thrones*, "Daenerys I"</sub>

And there are multiple mentions of fourteen years since Robert took the Iron Throne and Dany turning fourteen.

> They were on the far side of the Dothraki sea when Jhiqui brushed the soft swell of Dany's stomach with her fingers and said, "Khaleesi, you are with child."
>
> "I know," Dany told her.
>
> It was her fourteenth name day.
>
> <sub>*A Game of Thrones*, "Daenerys III"</sub>

So the series starts fourteen-ish years after Robert's Rebellion which took place from 282 AC to 283 AC with Dany being born not long after in 284 AC. Therefore, it takes place in 298 AC.

Comment: I'm sure there are a few other ways to work it out as well, if it's not explicitly stated somewhere like _The World of Ice and Fire_ that I've completely missed.

Comment: *The World of Ice and Fire* actually gives Robert's death as 298. But that doesn't tell us whether Jon Arryn died the same year or the previous year (see my edit).

Comment: @TopherBrennan If you're asking for more detailed events for how we know all sorts of things happen in the same year you're going to start fraying into too broad territory and so question closure. [Jon Arryn's death is covered here](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest/Calculations_Ages_(Continued)#Jon_Arryn), as are most of the things you're probably interested in.